# Using JCraft Jsch - executing sshpass command is unsuccessful

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch, sshpass

Need to establish a remote ssh into machine2 from a machine1. Trying the code below using ssh.but not succssfull. Ran a file creation command before &after the sshpass request to verify. file is created in Machine1 , but not worked in Machine2.
 Pls help. Is there any other options

```
String Cl_samp= new String("sshpass -p "xxxx" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@XXX.XX.115.71");
try{    
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session session_r=jsch.getSession(user, XXX.XX.115.70, 22);
            session_r.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session_r.setPassword(password);
        session_r.setConfig(config);
        session_r.connect();
        ChannelExec(session_r, "ls -la >>result.txt")
        ChannelExec(session_r, Cl_samp);
        ChannelExec(session_r, "ls -la >>result.txt")
        session_r.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");

        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
private void ChannelExec(Session session_1, String Serv_cmd) throws IOException{

    try {
        Channel channel;
        channel = session_1.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(Serv_cmd);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();
        System.out.print("Server-"+"command:"+Serv_cmd+" \n");
        channel.disconnect();           
        } catch (JSchException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContactEditorUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

   }
```

Comment: _"But it's not successful"_ -- You have to tell us how it's not successful, and include any error message and/or stack trace (format a stack trace as code, not blockquote).

Comment: Ran a file creation command before &after the sshpass request to verify. file is created in Machine1, but did not work in Machine2.<code updated>

Answer (score 0):

```
ChannelExec(session_r, "ls -la >>result.txt")
ChannelExec(session_r, Cl_samp);
ChannelExec(session_r, "ls -la >>result.txt")
```

Each channel that you create will run independently of the others. In the common case (making an ssh connection to a unix server), each channel will invoke a separate shell instance, which runs the command that you specify and then exits. Running `ssh` in one channel won't affect subsequent commands launched in different channels.

To invoke ssh on the second host and get it to run a command on the third host, you need to do the whole thing through one exec channel, something like this:

```
String Cl_samp= "sshpass -p '...' ssh -o ... root@... 'ls -la >>result.txt'";
ChannelExec(session_r, Cl_samp);
```

This adds the command to be invoked to the `ssh` command line, which causes ssh (running on the second host) to request the command to be run on the third host.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried as you mentioned above. But still no luck. If I run the command:   sshpass -p '...' ssh -o ... root@... 'ls -la >>result.txt' directly from putty session of machine2, it works, file got created in machine3. The issue is when launching the same from the Java code.